# RDP with Chromebook on Ubuntu Instance in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, rdp, chromebook

Someone could kindly explain to me how I can connect in RDP from chromebook to instance Ubuntu Compute engine ? 
I installed ubuntu-desktop and xrdp (via an online guide), but unfortunately the host rejects the connection. 
The HTTP connection is active on the host in question.

I tried to connect via the application of Chrome, Chrome RDP on both versions that are on the app store, but the host is not reachable.
I tried using "mstsc.exe" from Windows 7 and I can connect without problems, displaying the desktop of ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: As you say you can connect using Windows 7 RDP client to your Ubuntu VM instance, I assume you've opened RDP TCP port 3389 of your instance's network firewall?

Comment: Hi. The TCP port 3389 is open on network configuration of VM Instance. 

Allow RDP from anywhere
Source Ranges:
0.0.0.0/0
Allowed Protocols or Ports:
tcp:3389

Comment: I tried this extension and it works. Give it a try:  
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-rdp/cbkkbcmdlboombapidmoeolnmdacpkch

Comment: did the RDP extension I posted work for you?

Comment: You can take a look at this [post](http://timbot-inc.blogspot.com/2015/11/cloud-workstation-howto-chromebook.html)